# "Like" button on CMS site not pulling title or description

Tags: facebook-like

I am trying to implement the like button onto article and blog pages on a CMS site, but it is either pulling the title or description or neither when it posts the link on my Facebook wall. It also sometimes pulls the wrong image.

Example page:

http://www.midwesthomemag.com/media/Blogs/Ask-the-Experts/November-2011/Communicating-Design-Ideas/

I have many different pages, so I need it to pull the title, description, image and URL automatically rather than entering it for each page.

I have tried using the Debugger, but I don't know what the correct properties are that I should add into the meta fields to automate the process.

Please advise on what I can do to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a generator for the basic necessary tags under 'Step 2' on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - try those and see if the debug tool at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug accepts them - it will point out any errors

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used the tag generator, but the problem is that I need some of those tags to auto-fill depending on the article. Are there certain words that I can put in the fields (or leave blank) in order to automatically pull the title, description and URL for each page?

Comment: Just fill in the tags on each article from the article's own information / image / etc - if you're not programming your own site see if there's a plugin available for the CMS you use which will do this for you - there's plugins for most of the big CMS systems including wordpress, drupal, joomla, etc

Comment: Unfortunately, there are too many articles and posts for me to be able to go into each page and fill in the information. I removed the button fro the template code on my example page for now, but if any knows of a code to auto-fill the tags, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

generate the og meta tags according to the doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

just put them in the head section of your page it will automatically generate what you need when you share/like your link

---

Edit :

can't you use the page title and description generated by your CMS and fill the og tags ?

```
<title>TITLE_FROM_CMS</title>
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="DESCRIPTION_FROM_CMS">
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE_FROM_CMS" />
<meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION_FROM_CMS" />
```

Comment: Will it automatically generate if I leave the content fields blank? I'm entering it into a CMS template that will be applied to many individual article pages with unique titles and descriptions, so I won't be able to edit the content fields for each.